# Regex allow only numeric, one '$' in first position and one decimal - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently i have a RegEx which allows only numeric

```
if (/$^\d+([.]?\d{0,50})?$/.test(value)
```

Basically i need a `RegEx` which should allow

```
only numeric
one decimal point
one $ character
```

I have added `$` in the existing expressing, but that does not seem to be the solution. How to achieve the above all 3 scenarios

Comment: `if (/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$?$/.test(value)) { /* good */ }` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't seem to work. do u have the working example?

Comment: [It works for me](https://regex101.com/r/RsyTfE/1). No issues. It matches numeric values, only 1 point, and a `$` char (at the end). What do you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your time. I wanted `$` should be in the first place. I have updated the `regex` as well

Comment: try this /^\$\d+(\.\d+)?/

Comment: @Matarishvan Do you mean that "$" is allowed?  Or do you mean a single "$" is allowed before a valid numeric value?

Comment: @caedmon single `$` should be allowed which should be in the first position, Then numeric with one decimal

Comment: @Matarishvan Try [`/^\$?\d+(?:\.\d{1,50})?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/ELD8Qi/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, this should work:

```
/^(\$|\$\d+(\.\d{0,50})?)$/
```

This regex will accept a value of `"$"` as well as a numeric value with `$` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for

```
/^\$?\d+(?:\.\d{1,50})?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ELD8Qi/1)

**Details**

- `^` - [start of a string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `\$?` - an optional `$` char ([must be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions))
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,50})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,50}` - one to fifty digits
- `$` - [end of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).